# Conserving Battery with iOS CLLocationManager

Tags: ios, core-location

I'm attempting to be power-efficient with my use of CLLocationManager, given the constraints of my application:

1. If app is in Mode 'A', provide as much & as accurate location data
   as possible.
2. If app is in Mode 'B', check in at least once every 10 minutes
   with 'good enough' (~500m maybe) location data
3. Mode 'A' and Mode 'B' must both work while the app is in the
   background.

Due to constraint 3, I've added 'location' to UIBackgroundModes in my plist. 
I am configuring my core location manager like so:

```
- (CLLocationManager *)manager {
    if (_manager == nil) {
        _manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        _manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        _manager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
        _manager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
        _manager.delegate = self;
    }

    return _manager;
}
```

I've also defined an enumeration like so:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, LocationMonitoringMode) {
    LocationMonitoringModeSignificantChanges, //Mode B
    LocationMonitoringModeContinuous, //Mode A
};
```

which I use like so:

```
- (void)setLocationMonitoringMode:(LocationMonitoringMode)mode {
    if (mode == LocationMonitoringModeContinuous) {

        [self.manager stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
        [self.manager startUpdatingLocation];

    } else if (mode == LocationMonitoringModeSignificantChanges) {

        [self.manager stopUpdatingLocation];
        [self.manager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    }
}
```

Questions: Is this 'toggling' an effective way of conserving battery with CLLocationManager?  There is obviously a big difference btwn power consumption using `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` & `kCLLocationAccuracy3Kilometers` (gps vs cell tower radios). But is there also a large cost btwn, say `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` & `kCLLocationAccuracyNearest10Meters`?

Comment: `kCLLocationAccuracyBest` & `kCLLocationAccuracyNearest10Meters` will cost the same.  Anything below about 100m requires the device to power up the GPS chip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question:

Yes. The toggling looks just fine. You do not have to create two separate location manager instances.

According to Apple documents on CoreLocation
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html

> The significant-change location service provides accuracy that’s good enough for most apps and represents a power-saving alternative to the standard location service. The service uses Wi-Fi to determine the user’s location and report changes in that location, allowing the system to manage power usage much more aggressively than it could otherwise.

Second question:

You can use Apple's energy diagnostics instruments to see at what desiredAccuracy level GPS chip is powered up. Our most recent investigation suggests that the GPS chip is powered when the desiredAccuracy or distanceFilter value is less than 100 meters. Energy usage values that instruments provides are very coarse for me to draw any direct co-relation between desiredAccuracy and battery usage. However, according to the popular wisdom, not turning on the GPS chip when you can is a good proxy for energy savings.